# How to make menu in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, menu

Menu are looking very nice in all website
so i want to make such menu so how to make that 
and when we select one menu then its color is changed so how this is possible
and even border is changed so how to make such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](http://www.seoconsultants.com/css/menus/tutorial/) is a link to an article that creates menu using css check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5(VS.80).aspx